# How to fix a very distorted mesh after having imported a BVH file with the Manuel Bastioni Lab

Tags: mesh, modifiers, shape-keys

I've been all day working with the [`Corrective Shape Keys`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/animation/corrective_shape_keys.html) and understood how they work. I need to modify the mesh manually with the [`Proportional Editing`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html) and then I should create a [`Shape Key`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/shape_keys/index.html) with the mesh modified correctly, but what I'm not able to do is to fix the legs of my character, because they became very damaged after that I have imported a [BVH file](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/graphics/Courses/cs-838-1999/Jeff/BVH.html). I tried to modify them with the *Proportional Editing* tool, but the job done is not good, since it's difficult to carefully alter the mesh, especially behind the knee. Any suggestions? Is there a way to fix it decently?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Other than proportional edit, the following techniques might be handy.

- Move vertecies along normal :<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- Smooth Mesh : Tool shelf > Mesh Tools > Deform: Smooth Vertex
- To Sphere : <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- Shrink Wrap Modifier (use vertex group to specify vertecies)

Hope they help.

Comment: I tried,but unsuccesfull. you can see here what happened https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fWKB8W3OaivYpvZ770weWVJk1AIWlRdg ; and you can find the blender file here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XtBpBy0cPBktEzFnaqgG5z7MfgIC-qOW

Comment: I am terribly sorry, I meant "smooth" for relax. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/smooth.html

Comment: The methods above are methods to help you with local deformations. If you need an Full Auto Relaxing tool, you'll need a very smart AI

Comment: I have disabled the muscles inside the manuel bastioni lab and I have created a new character and it worked. So,the problem maybe is inside the constraints used for the muscles,I'm talking about the stretch constraints mainly...

Comment: To be honest, I know nothing about the Manuel Bastioni Lab. However, I might be of help if you could provide us what you exactly did after you created the model. Did you do some posing? Or did it start like that from the first place? Also what happens when you turn off the modifiers and constrains from the panels?

Comment: sure,watch this : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mjbUvDA25dleGDCH45EZFDuMDoLTQNct